# Gstreamer Missing Audio in MP4

Tags: gstreamer, mp4

This command adds a text to the video, but the audio is missing in the output MP4 file:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=input.mp4 name=src ! decodebin ! textoverlay text="My Text" ! x264enc ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=output.mp4
```

How can I fix this, so that the audio is preserved?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
gst-launch-1.0 \
filesrc location=input.mp4 name=src\
  ! decodebin name=demuxer \
demuxer. ! queue \
  ! textoverlay text="My Text" \
  ! x264enc ! muxer. \
demuxer. ! queue \
  ! audioconvert ! voaacenc ! muxer. \
mp4mux name=muxer \
  ! filesink location=output.mp4
```

Comment: It is usually safer to add queues after the demuxer outputs (or any element that has 1 input and multiple outputs) to decouple the threads and avoid deadlocks if one branch needs to block and wait for the other.

Comment: @thiagoss or anyone. Is there a way to pass the audio through without re-encoding? Thanks

Comment: In gst-launch-1.0 you can use a demuxer instead of decodebin but that means that you should know beforehand the filetype as decodebin will automatically pick that for you. And then there is a chance that you can just drop the audio encoder and just link a parser and put its output directly to the muxer assuming it supports the original audio format. Writing your own application might improve your possibilities.